# Reading from file, splitting results and putting them in arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, strtok

I am given file which contains string like `1,2;3,4;0,4;2,5`. Those are key - value pairs delimited by `;`. When i runt the code below i can see that everything looks ok and i get back correct key-value pairs, but when i actually try to insert them into array, i get segmentation fault. Any advice or suggestions how to fix this will be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){


FILE *f = fopen("test.txt", "rb");
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
int fsize = ftell(f);
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

int n[fsize+1];
char *string = malloc(fsize + 1);

fread(string, fsize, 1, f);
fclose(f);

int first;
int second;

char* first_split;

char *rest2;
char *rest;

while(first_split = strtok_r(string, ";", &rest))
{

        char * second_split = strtok_r(first_split, ",", &rest2);
        first_split = rest2;
        first = atol(second_split);
        second = atol(first_split);
        printf("n[%d]=%d " ,first, second);

    /* n['first']=second; */


        string = rest;
}

}
```

Comment: `int x = atol(...)` — wrong type. `second_split` is not checked for NULL. This is just for starter...

Comment: You don't ensure that the string is null terminated.  You allocate space for the null, but you don't use `calloc()` and you don't null terminate it.  Therefore, your code has undefined behaviour.  Add `string[fsize] = '\0';` after the `fread()`.  You should check that you get as much data as you expect from the read; you should check that the file is opened successfully before using it. You should check that the `malloc()` is successful.  It might be a good idea to allow for the newline at the end of the line.  You should check the nullness of `second_split`.

Comment: Your use of `string = rest;` is unorthodox at best.  The correct way to continue the search is to set the first argument to `strtok_r()` to NULL on subsequent searches of the same string.  What you do may work, but it is far from guaranteed.  Since you don't have either newlines or `fflush()` calls to ensure the output is printed, you don't know how far the code gets before crashing.  When debugging, make sure your output appears — include a newline or add a `fflush()`.  It's a good idea to echo inputs — after the file is read, and as you find each token.

Comment: `first` <-> `second` ?